# What is this medium format military rangefinder camera?

Tags: medium-format, rangefinder, camera-identification, film-cameras

I came across pictures of an old photography magazine, that features pictures of a camera that seems to be a **Medium Format** camera with interchangeable lenses. I am curious to try and identify it, as it bears no logos and doesn't resemble anything I've seen before:

[image]

[image]

### **What is this camera?**

Comment: Medium format rangefinders like that were made a lot by Fuji, Plaubel, and Mamiya....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a 70mm Graflex KE-4 “Combat Graphic” made from 1953-1957.

[Graflex KE-4 Combat Graphic](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Combat_Graphic)

[image]
[image]

Comment: bigger than a "Texas Leica", it's "Gulliver's Contax" - classic!

Comment: It's good that it's camouflaged so nobody can see you using that gigantic flash bulb.